# Random-method that generates a UIInt8 instead of UIInt32?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to randomly generate the position for a sprite. I use the arc4random() method to get a range from 1 to 8.

```
 var randomFactor = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1

sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/8 * randomFactor, self.frame.height)
```

An error pops up telling me "UIInt32 is not convertible to UIInt8".
Is there a way to get around this or design the code differently to make it work? Like a solution where the random method isn't a UIInt32 but a UIInt8.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does this error pop up? I don't see anywhere that you're using `UInt8` or `UInt32`.

Comment: I think the arc4random is a UIInt32 and the CGPointMake requires me to use a UIInt8 if I want to "mix" around in it.

Comment: `CGPointMake` accepts `CGFloat` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert 'randomFactor' to a CGFloat:

```
var randomFactor = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1
var x = self.frame.width / 8 * CGFloat(randomFactor)
var y = self.frame.height
var position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```